# While resizing how to get dimensions as width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to get width and height values while I am resizing div and by css transition to make it count while it resize. For now I did it without resize with two inputs and here is the code how:

```js
document.getElementById("displayColor").style.background = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
function sizeWH(){
 var dr = document.getElementById("displayColor");
 var sv = document.getElementById("sizeValue");
 var w = document.getElementById("width").value;
 var h = document.getElementById("height").value;
 if(w==""){
 sv.innerHTML = 'Width: 0px; Height: '+h+'px;';
 
 }else if(h==""){
 sv.innerHTML = 'Width: '+w+'px; Height: 0px;';
 
 }else{
 dr.style.transition = 'width 0s linear 0s, height 0s linear 0s';
 dr.style.width = w+'px';
 dr.style.height = h+'px';
 sv.innerHTML = 'Width: '+w+'px; Height: '+h+'px;';
 }
}
```

```css
#displayColor{
 height: 30px;
 width: 510px;
 resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table name="size">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Width:</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="width" min="0"  step="1" oninput="sizeWH()" value="510" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Height:</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="height" min="0"  step="1" oninput="sizeWH()" value="30" /></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>Size values:</td>
   <td><div id="sizeValue">Width: 510px; Height: 30px;</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<tr>
      <td>Displayed:</td>
   <td><div id="displayColor"></div></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: To make it clear, you want height and width values of `<div id="displayColor">` as its dimensions are changing. Am i correct?

Comment: Yeah but when they are changing by added resize like on textarea, also not after the resize is finished but same time to update with transition, as I did with inputs, I don't know how to say on resize change get width and height.. @Rüzgar

Comment: Are you looking for the innerwidth property ? http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/

Comment: Sorry, i don't think that i understood your problem.

Comment: Pff I don't know how to ask, I added resize on div like textarea has resize: both; is css, and while resizing with that I watch to get widht and height not after i finish resizing but same time when i resize